# Recommended online academic presentation resources

Tags: presentation

I am always struggling with academic presentation skills. Do you have some recommended online courses or textbooks? Courses are better. I cannot find any courses about academic presentations on Coursea. I want to learn both slide making and speaking.

Comment: "Even a Geek Can Speak"by Joey Asher. Also: Practice.

Comment: Are you primarily interested in math?

Comment: @Buffy Yes, I am interested in theoretical computer science and mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tip: Present the topic as if you were genuinely interested in teaching someone about it. Start with a hook or some practical application of what you're going to be discussing that most people in your audience would be interested in. Then, provide relevant academic background for your topic. This will set you up to expand on the introductory points made in your background throughout your main discussion. And lastly, at all times throughout your presentation, remember that you are really trying to help someone understand something that is of interest to you. Presenting should always feel like teaching or helping someone. And most people love the feeling of helping others. So I hope that you can draw strength from that.